# Can not install a new language on Xfce4

Tags: xfce, language-support

I'm trying to install Arabic language but when I press on " Install / Remove language " from " language support " these messages shows up:

first message
[image: First message]

second message
[image: Second message]

Comment: Installing a new language must be done from a user with [administrative privileges](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-admin-explain.html).

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I'm a new ubuntu user , Could you please tell me what should I do ?!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem is. Can you please open a terminal window, run the command `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, and show us the complete output by editing your question. That might give us a hint about what's causing the problem.

Comment: sudo apt install policykit-1-gnome